# broken owncloud php + repository

Tags: apt, php, owncloud-server

Yesterday I failed to successfully install owncloud on my ubuntu desktop. The current issue that I am facing is when I go to my owncloud page I get the error:

PHP is configured to populate raw post data. Since PHP 5.6 this will lead to PHP throwing notices for perfectly valid code.

To fix this issue set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 in your php.ini

This was not a setting in anp php.ini file, I added it anyway but to no avail. When I tried to update owncloud I got the error that I was missing a public key so I got I new key using apt-key. I now get the warning:

W: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.gpg: Signature by key F9EA4996747310AE79474F44977C43A8BA684223 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

I understand that I may be too mired in my mistakes and lack of knowledge to be helped but I ask for advice on what do do, and if it is a lost cause how to remove everything. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with owncloud repos not supporting Ubuntu 16.04 yet. As a workaround you can manually download *.deb files for 15.10. But that's not very nice solution.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: download  [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client) at the bottom of the page is link for direct download